# Linear transformation. Prove the statement or give an example in which it is false.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm working on a Linear Algebra assignment and I have to prove the statement or give an example in which it's false. Throughout, let $T : V\to W$ be a linear transformation where $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional.

1) if $V=W$, then $\text{ker}(T)$ (is contained in) $\text{im}(T)$.

2) if $\text{dim}(V)=5$ and $\text{dim}(W)=4$, then $\text{ker}(T)$ (does not equal) $\{ 0 \}$.

Comment: Hint: For number 2, see if you can use the rank-nullity theorem to work out whether the statement is true. For number 1, try to come up with some simple examples by hand to get an idea whether the statement is true or false.

Comment: What have you tried? (it is considered poor etiquette on Math.SE to post a homework question without detailing what you have tried. You will increase your chances of getting a response if you do)

Comment: Counterexamples are hard, but the other one can be done from base definitions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) consider $T : \mathbb{K}^2 \to \mathbb{K}^2$, with $(x,y) \mapsto (0,x)$.

What is kernel, what is image, prove it's linear...

2) Rank-Nullity is the slickest way.

$$R = \dim (T(V))\\ N = \dim(\ker(T))$$

Then $$R + N = \dim V$$

If $\ker(T) = \{0\}$, then $N = 0$
so $R = 5 = \dim V$, but how do you find a $5$-dimensional space with just 4 dimensions?

Comment: remember to mark correct if you like it